# How to set iframe height:auto in HTML5

Tags: css, iframe

I'm trying to make iframe height auto(100%), so searched lot of examples.

But the problem is... it does not working good in IE, only works in Chrome.

```
<div class="stockIframe ">
<iframe src="http://google.com" onload="autoResize(this)" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe> 
</div>

html,body { height: 100% }
.stockIframe {  width:100%; height:100%; }
.stockIframe iframe {  width:100%; height:100%; border:0;overflow:hidden }


<script>
function autoResize(i)
{
    var iframeHeight=
    (i).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    (i).height=iframeHeight+20;
}


</script>
```

Anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: in any case, remove the width- and height-tags from the HTML element, if you have it in CSS as well

Comment: For me it works fine in IE11(win7), without the autoResize()-function that is

Comment: Update your html,body-CSS: `html,body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}`

Comment: And for no scrolling on the iframe, use `scrolling="no"` inside the element (not CSS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem in your code, but don't forget the `style` tag

I tested it on IE 11 and it works.

```
<div class="stockIframe ">
    <iframe src="http://google.com" onload="autoResize(this)" height="100%" width="100"></iframe> 
</div>

<style>
   html,body { height: 100% }
   .stockIframe {  width:100%; height:100%; }
   .stockIframe iframe {  width:100%; height:100%; border:0;overflow:hidden }
</style>

<script>
   function autoResize(i) {
     var iframeHeight=
     (i).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
     (i).height=iframeHeight+20;
   } 
</script>
```