# Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame. I own both the website

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two websites example.com & example.tech I want to embed a page from example.tech into example.com

I have embedded it using iframe but the problem is height of the iframe is not auto. I don't want to show the iframe scrollbar.

So I tried solution from here: [How to set iframe height:auto in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134084/how-to-set-iframe-heightauto-in-html5) but I got this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin 
"https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Again I found this [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) but it is not working for me.

Help me to come out of this situation. Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score -5):

**JQuery Iframe Resizer Plugin**

http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/ This is the solution!